# I am getting an error "Incorrect syntax near '-'. when executing a procedure

Tags: sql-server

While executing the procedure shown below, I am getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'

I am trying to use `OPENQUERY` to execute a procedure. I am expecting to run this procedure without the error message 102 which is appearing now.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [PlexSprocs].[PUR_xPCN_Supply_Inv_Valuation_DTL_VEI_00]  
    (@PCN INT = -1,
     @PCN_Group VARCHAR(100) = '',
     @Item_No VARCHAR(25) = '',
     @Description  VARCHAR(800) = '',
     @Location VARCHAR(50) = '',
     @Building_Key INT = -1,
     @Item_Group_Key INT = - 1,
     @Consignment INT = -1,
     @Vender_Managed INT = -1,
     @Item_Type_Key INT = -1)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @Sproc VARCHAR(MAX),
            @Seperator VARCHAR(10),
            @FullCommand VARCHAR(MAX),
            @Parameter_List VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Seperator = ''','''
    SET @Parameter_List = CONCAT('''', @PCN,'''')
                + ',' + CONCAT('''', @PCN_Group,'''')    
                + ',' + CONCAT('''', @Item_No,'''')
                + ',' + CONCAT('''', @Description,'''')
                + ',' + CONCAT('''', @Location,'''')
                + ',' + CONCAT('''', @Building_Key,'''')
                + ',' + CONCAT('''', @Item_Group_Key,'''')
                + ',' + CONCAT('''', @Consignment,'''')
                + ',' + CONCAT('''', @Vender_Managed,'''')
                + ',' + CONCAT('''', @Item_Type_Key,'''')
    -- SET @FullCommand = @Sproc + @Parameter_List
    SET @SQL = N'
          SELECT
            Q.*
          FROM OPENQUERY
          (
            POLODBC,
            ''
            exec sproc79870_11901675_1328255
                            '''''+@Parameter_List+'''''
        '') AS Q
        '
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Comment: Why are you using parametrised dynamic SQL here? This is **wide** open to SQL Injection and you need to fix it. The error you have is a saving grace, as  you you **not** write statements like this. I actually see no reason for the above the be dynamic either.

Comment: What do you suppose would happen if someone passed `''; USE master; DROP DATABASE SDPlex;--` for the value of `@Description`?

Comment: Why do you need to use `OPENQUERY` here? If you must, then I suggest safely injecting the parameters, not just raw concatenation. So that would instead be `'''' + REPLACE(@Description, '''','''''') + ''''`

Comment: Well, just comment the `exec sp_executesql @SQL` and write `SELECT @SQL` - execute the routine, then copy and paste the output and debug it.

Comment: Can You show us value of @Parameter_List ?